# Chrome debugger does not iterate _.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, each

I have a javascript code like this:

```
_.each(node.readLines, function(line) {
  // Mark read-lines
  start = line;
  that._editor.session.addGutterDecoration(start - 1, 'editor_read_decoration');
  that._gutterDecorations[start - 1] = 'editor_read_decoration';
});
```

When debugging it with Chrome, the debugger does iterate the loop of this `_.each` function although `node.readLines` has five elements. It just halts at `_.each` and with the next step it goes to the next statement after this `_.each` statement without going inside it. Of course the statements inside the `_.each` are executed, but in the background. And it does not make any difference if I click the **"step into"** or **"step over"** command of the chrome debugger.  I realized that happens always I use this `_.each` function. 
How can I debug the statements inside this functions and iterate through all iterations for `node.readLines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Step Into`, you should step into the implementation of `_.each()` in lodash or underscore.js. If it's minimized, the code will be unreadable there. You'll have to do some additional stepping in that code before it gets to your iteration function, and you'll need to use `Step Into` there as well.

What I generally do to debug code like this is set a breakpoint on the first line of the callback function.

Comment: Yes, setting breakpoint in the callback function fixed the problem. Thanks